# Append a bearer token to a git request or disable core dump

Tags: git, bearer-token, coredump

I have a problem with git and core dumps. 
I try to operate git via CLI commands and the authentication method is a bearer token. Since I run those commands in a AWS Lambda, I only have the /tmp/ directory to work with. Therefore I write the authentication token as httpHeader into the git request. But last time git crashed and produced a core dump, which printed the command into the console, together with the bearer token. Does anyone know, if it is possible to append the token in another type or to disable or redirect the core dump logs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most git services I know of allow token authentication via the password field.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
My problem with this solution is, that my company has a SSO Authentication, which means, I have no real profile with username and password at the git service.

Comment: If you can generate an access token in the git service, that should still work.

Comment: I've tried that, it locks the account every time because of too many failed tries.

Comment: Then contact your IT department for help with how to do this - or use SSH.